# Why would I have to do chart.draw twice to get a Google pie chart to display?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, charts, google-visualization

I have a page in an app that displays all sorts of ticket metrics from several different ticketing systems we use. I use the same function to build each of the charts and display them:

```
function drawChart(chartData, chartStyle, chartTitle, chartSpanID) {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  
  data.addColumn('string', 'Hour');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Tickets');
  data.addRows(chartData);
  
  if(chartStyle == "column"){
    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById(chartSpanID));
    var options = {title:chartTitle,chartArea: {left: 30, top:20, bottom:30, right:10},animation:{startup: true, duration:2000}}
    };
  
  if(chartStyle == "pie"){
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById(chartSpanID));
    var options = {title:chartTitle, 
                   chartArea:{left: 0, top:20, bottom:10, right: 0},
                   is3D: true,
                   sliceVisibilityThreshold: .01,
                   animation:{startup: true,easing: 'in', duration:1000},
                   pieResidueSliceLabel: "Other( < 1%)"};
};
chart.draw(data, options);

}
```

This works for 13 of the 14 charts displayed on the page. 8 Columns and 5 out of 6 pie charts all display perfectly. One of the pie charts will ONLY display if I draw the chart a second time.

```
function drawChart(chartData, chartStyle, chartTitle, chartSpanID) {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  
  data.addColumn('string', 'Hour');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Tickets');
  data.addRows(chartData);
  
  if(chartStyle == "column"){
    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById(chartSpanID));
    var options = {title:chartTitle,chartArea: {left: 30, top:20, bottom:30, right:10},animation:{startup: true, duration:2000}}
    };
  
  if(chartStyle == "pie"){
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById(chartSpanID));
    var options = {title:chartTitle, 
                   chartArea:{left: 0, top:20, bottom:10, right: 0},
                   is3D: true,
                   sliceVisibilityThreshold: .01,
                   animation:{startup: true,easing: 'in', duration:1000},
                   pieResidueSliceLabel: "Other( < 1%)"};
};
chart.draw(data, options);
chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

The data is delivered correctly, all calls are made through google.charts.setOnLoadCallback, it all works just fine once called again... so why is it only working on the second call? Why just the one chart that doesn't display as expected? What have I missed?

Comment: My guess is the first function chart.draw() is calling chart variable for column charts and second function is calling chart variable for pie charts...something along these lines.

Comment: Is there anything special about the different pie chart?

Comment: are you calling `setOnLoadCallback` multiple times? only needs to be called once per page load.

Comment: @user1280483 - nothing special. 3 items, 3 numbers. Other pie charts same size and data structure load without issue with a single chart.draw.

Comment: @WhiteHat - yes, I am. I can restructure it so that isn't the case, I'm totally down to give it a try. I still don't know why it would only affect one of the six pie charts, and no matter when in the order of things I tried to handle it.